# initialize winsock without wsadata using WSAStartup?

Tags: c, winsock

Basically I wanted to know if you can initialize a winsock without creating WSADATA variable or feeding the WSADATA value directly to WSAStartup function?

I tried :

```
WSAStartup(0x202, NULL);
WSAStartup(0x202, (WSADATA *)0x00);
```

with above, the socket fails to `recv()` but then again it start to work if you have:

```
WSADATA wsaData;
WSAStartup(0x202, &wsaData);
```

Based on documentation, it says "It allows an application or DLL to specify the version of Windows Sockets required and retrieve details of the specific Windows Sockets implementation". So, could we not directly define a memory location to store the returned value?

Comment: The documentation says you must provide a pointer to a `WSADATA` struct. So no, `WSAStartup(0x202, (WSADATA *)0x00);` won't work. You also omitted to check the value returned by `WSAStartup`.

Comment: ***Why*** would you want to do that?  [The function is documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup) as receiving a pointer to a `WSADATA` structure.  Even if it didn't fail on the version of Windows you're developing on, the next time that version is updated or someone ran the application on another system or the phase of the moon changed it could very well fail.  Deliberately invoking undefined behavior is a ***bad*** idea.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically I wanted to know if you can initialize a winsock without creating WSADATA variable or feeding the WSADATA value directly to WSAStartup function?

The call to `WSAStartup()` is required, otherwise most Winsock functions will fail with an `WSANOTINITIALISED` error.  And `WSAStartup()` itself requires a pointer to allocated memory to fill in with `WSADATA` data.  This is not optional.

> So, could we not directly define a memory location to store the returned value?

That is exactly what declaring a variable does.  But more generally, yes you can certainly pass in any non-NULL memory address, as long as it is a valid memory address within the calling process, and has been allocated to hold *at least* `sizeof(WSADATA)` number of bytes.